# ksoftirqd maxing out for network interfaces

Tags: networking, linux-networking, packetloss, interrupts, irq

We have a Debian server with one link to the internal VLAN, and one to the external - both connect directly to the same switch.

On both links, we're intermittently seeing an unusually high amount of bad receive events, as well as high latency.

```
Kernel  Interface  table
Iface   MTU        Met    RX-OK       RX-ERR  RX-DRP     RX-OVR     TX-OK       TX-ERR  TX-DRP  TX-OVR  Flg
ethA    1500       0      884347583   0       49965509   49965509   1697514631  0       0       0       BMRU
ethB    1500       0      1611102819  0       77615811   77615811   819321274   0       0       0       BMRU
```

We're also seeing the ksoftirqd processes for both interfaces max out at 90+% most of the time, even when things should ostensibly be quiet.

```
44 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  98.8  0.0   2557:46 ksoftirqd/3
51 root      20   0       0      0      0 R  85.6  0.0   2722:33 ksoftirqd/5
```

As I understand it, this means the server is maxing out the assigned CPU to process all the packets coming in on this interface. But even when we're seeing ~50Mbps coming in, (and identical servers are handling >800Mbps) these processes can max out and RX-DRPs skyrocket. irqbalance is running, and /proc/interrupts confirms that these CPUs aren't busy handling really anything else.

Are there any clear potential causes for this?

Would assigning multiple CPUs (via smp_affinity) to handle the interrupts for those interfaces potentially help? I'm unable to find a single example of someone assigning multiple CPUs to a single network interface, so it seems unconventional at best, system-break-worthy at worst.

This has been causing issues in production for a while, so I'd happily accept any potential workaround.